# Why does a git pathspec starting with a wildcard * not match in subdirectories?

Tags: regex, git, pattern-matching

TL;DR:

## Why doesn't `pathspec` `*.txt` match subdirectories, but `'*.txt'` does?

---

## An example

Say I have a git repo with a file tree like so:

```
file.txt
dir/file.txt
```

Both files contain a character `a`. If I want to `git grep` for that `a`, but I limit my search to `.txt` extensions, I'd try

```
git grep a -- *.txt
```

However, this only returns the match in `file.txt`, but not the match from `dir/file.txt`.

In git, everything after the `--` is a `pathspec`, which can be read about in `gitglossary(7)` (`man 7 gitglossary`). There, the description is a bit lengthy and unclear to me, but I understand the following from this quote:

> [...] in particular, * and ? can match directory separators.

I understand that `*` should match `dir/file`, but it obviously does not.

Instead if I do

```
git grep a -- '*.txt'
```

I *do* get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line :

```
git grep a -- *.txt
```

the *.txt is interpreted by the current shell

while in :

```
git grep a -- '*.txt'
```

it is passed to git and used by git with defined behaviour

Comment: So since I'm using bash, bash expands `*.txt` to `file.txt` (the only match at the repo root), and then `git grep a -- file.txt` is run?

Comment: @Erik: yes, exactly. It's not specific to Git, it's general to the shell with any command.

Comment: yes, it's the same with for example the find command: 'find . -name *.txt ' vs 'find . -name "*.txt" '

Comment: This is maybe worth a separate question (and possibly has been asked elsewhere, I'll search), but why does `git add -- *.txt` add tracked and untracked files in subdirectories? Why doesn't my shell (bash) not expand that before passing it to git?

Comment: @Erik Were there any files matching that pattern in the directory where you ran it? By default, when shell globbing finds no matches, it leaves the pattern untouched. Then, `git` would see `*.txt` as-is and do its own expansion, which can span into subdirectories, as you've observed.